# I want to Fetch the post to the user's Profile

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I want to Fetch the post to the user's Profile, The profile is already fetching the bio
i am new to programming and laravel as well please help

**Here's My Controller:-**

```
public function index($post)
     {

       $post = Post::findOrFail($post);
       return view('profile.index', [
         'post' => $post,
       ]);


     }
```

**Here's my view:-**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><a href="/bio-create">.Add Bio</a>  </button>

                <div class="card-header"><h2>{{Auth::user()->username}}</h2></div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    {{$user->profile->bio}}

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"> <a href="/post">Add Info</a>

            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<h1> Posts </h1>
@foreach($post as $row)
{{$row->title}}

@endforeach

@endsection
```

Couldn't figure out what how to complete the @froeach loop

**Here's My Route:-**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();


Route::get('/profile/{user}', 'ProfilesController@index')->name('profile.show');

Route::get('/bio-create', 'ProfilesController@create');
Route::post('/b', 'ProfilesController@store');
Route::get('/post', 'PostsController@create');
Route::post('/p', 'PostsController@store');
Route::get('/profile/{user}/{post}', 'PostsController@index');
```

The last **Route** is the route that i am using 
i don't even know if its right way to do it

**Please Help** and **Thanks In Advance**

Comment: So what you want to do is, when you go to user/show, you want all the posts of the user?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a `UserPostController` with an `ìndex`-Method, which could look like this:

```
public function index(User $user)
{
    return view('profile.index', [
        'posts' => $user->posts,
    ]);
}
```

A route which would look like this:

```
Route::get('/your-name/{user}/', 'UserPostController@index');
```

For this to work you need to have a relation between `Post` and `User` where `User` is most likely the parent and therefor the `Owning-Side`.

Comment: i did as u asked me to do but now i cant access my username data which is coming form the **"ProfilesController"** and can u please show me how to display the codes i am using to display it is ```<h1> All Forms </h1>
@if(count($posts) > 0)
  @foreach($posts as $post)
<div class="well">
  <h3>{{$post->title}}</h3>
  <small>written on {{$post->created_at}}</small>
</div>

@endforeach
@else
   <p>No Forms Found</p>
@endif``` and the error i am getting is **"count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable"**

Comment: Does your User-Model have a relation with post? e.g. `hasMany()` ?

Comment: Yes.. user model has many posts and post model belongs to user class

Comment: Sorry, it should be `$user->posts` and not `$user->posts()`!